# Excel combobox disabled after Microsoft updates

Tags: excel, combobox

Microsoft Excel December 2014 updates have left my combobox disabled. 
Is there any way to get them working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the file MSForms.exd from all the Temp subfolder in the user's profile (AppData\Local\Temp) to get the combobox working.

for excel delete this file :

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd

Script:

```
del %temp%\vbe\*.exd

del %temp%\excel8.0\*.exd

del %appdata%\microsoft\forms\*.exd

del %appdata%\microsoft\local\*.exd

del %appdata%\Roaming\microsoft\forms\*.exd

del %temp%\word8.0\*.exd

del %temp%\PPT11.0\*.exd
```

Comment: Thanks Rupesh. That worked! But I am sure this is not a permanent solution. I hope Microsoft is working on fixing the bug from their last update.